# jQuery does not show content with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I am trying to get a content appear after sometime after making an ajax request with jQuery but I am getting some trouble with it.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'content.php',
            data: '&go=' + tab,
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout("pencil()",3250);
                setTimeout('$("#content").html(data).fadeIn()',5000);
            }
        });
```

The problem is that the "content" is not loaded this way after 5 seconds. However if I put it without the setTimeout it appears right away - but that way it smashes the animation.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your jQuery call in a function

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'content.php',
    data: '&go=' + tab,
    success: function (data) {
        setTimeout(pencil, 3250); //pass in a function reference preferably. 
        setTimeout(function(){$("#content").html(data).fadeIn()}, 5000); //wrap it in a function
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete example and the notification to pass in a function reference instead :)

Answer (score 4):

You are using the variable `data` in the string passed to `setTimeout`, but that variable will no longer exist when the string is executed.

You can fix this by using a function object instead of a string:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#content").html(data).fadeIn() 
}, 5000);
```

This works because the value of `data` is held in a closure.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably putting jquery code in the setTimeout in string input. 
Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#content").html(data).fadeIn()},5000);
```

I think this should work. The problem with your previous approach is setTimeout cannot run functions with inputs for example if you wrote "pencil(data);" it wouldn't work either.